# Always use next sequence in Serial Column (no user value allowed)

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

In PostgreSQL i would like to create a table with an auto-increment column where the user cannot specify custom values.

In Oracle you have two ways to create auto increment columns.

In this first example the id column is automatically incremented if the user doesn't sepcificy a value. This is the current implementation of SERIAL in postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab ( 
   id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS DENTITY,
   description VARCHAR2(30) 
);
```

In the next example the id column is **always** automatically incremented and the user cannot specify any other value.

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
  id          NUMBER ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

I would like to know the equivalent of the second example in postgres?

Comment: You need a trigger to do this.

Comment: trigger shall "rewrite" the value from sequence, despite the value defined by user. btw - this behaviour will give user illusion that his value was accepted, while trigger will consume value from sequence

Comment: @VaoTsun: you can always throw an exception in the trigger if the user supplied a value

Comment: yes, but then row does not go to the table. and raising just notice will be ignore by most applications

Comment: @VaoTsun: no, raising an exception will abort the transaction. It cannot be ignored by the application. See my answer

Comment: yes raising exception will abort transaction, so then the  row does not go to the table. and raising just notice `RAISE NOTICE|INFO|WARNING` will be ignored by most applications

Comment: @VaoTsun: so what? Then don't raise a notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by grant insert only for the specific columns:

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(i serial, x text, y int);
grant insert (x,y) on table t to abelisto;
grant usage on sequence t_i_seq to abelisto;
grant select on table t to abelisto;
```

And then:

```
postgres=# insert into t(i,x,y) values(10,'x',1);
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t
postgres=# insert into t(i,x,y) values(default,'x',1);
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t
postgres=# insert into t(x,y) values('x',1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from t;
 i | x | y 
---+---+---
 1 | x | 1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that the value is always taken from a sequence you need a trigger. There is no equivalent to `generated always` in Postgres:

```
create table foo (id integer not null primary key);
create sequence foo_id_seq;
alter sequence foo_id_seq owned by foo.id; -- this is essentially what `serial` does in the background

create function generate_foo_id()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.id := nextval('foo_id_seq');
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;    

create trigger foo_id_trigger
  before insert on foo
  for each row execute procedure generate_foo_id();
```

The above will silently replace any user supplied value for `foo.id` with the sequence value. If you want an explicit error when doing that, raise an exception in the trigger function:

```
create function generate_foo_id()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  if new.id is not null then 
     raise 'No manual value for id allowed';
  end if;
  new.id := nextval('foo_id_seq');
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Raising an exception aborts the current transaction and will force the application inserting the value to rollback and do it correctly.